# NS3_Can't run vanet-routing-compare.cc

Tags: debugging, ns-3, vehicle-routing

I'm new to NS3. I studied [vanet-routing-compair.cc](https://www.nsnam.org/doxygen/vanet-routing-compare_8cc_source.html) script. I tried to run it by these commands (vanet-routing-compare.cc is in scratch folder).

```
    ./waf --run scratch/vanet-routing-compare
    ./waf --run "vanet-routing-compare --scenario=1 --saveconfig=scenario1.txt"
```

But I'm getting confused with the results. I get following error messages.

```
msg="Could not connect callback to /NodeList/*/DeviceList/*/ns3::WifiNetDevice/Phy/PhyTxDrop", file=../src/core/model/config.cc, line=920 terminate called without an active exception

Command ['/home/azra/Desktop/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31/build/scratch/vanet-routing-compare'] terminated with signal SIGIOT. Run it under a debugger to get more information (./waf --run <program> --gdb").
```

And by using the gdb debugger, I see this message.

```
The program being debugged has been started already.
Start it from the beginning? (y or n) y
Starting program: /home/azra/Desktop/ns-allinone-3.31/ns-3.31/build/scratch/vanet-routing-    compare --scenario=1 --saveconfig=scenario1.txt
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libthread_db.so.1".
msg="Could not connect callback to /NodeList/*/DeviceList/*/ns3::WifiNetDevice /Phy/PhyTxDrop", file=../src/core/model/config.cc, line=920
terminate called without an active exception

Program received signal SIGABRT, Aborted.
__GI_raise (sig=sig@entry=6) at ../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/raise.c:51
51 }
```

I appreciate who can help me understand why this is happening and how I can solve it.

Comment: What's your code? What command are you trying to run exactly?

Comment: Thank you for your attention @the_new_james. I edited my question and added the link of the code and commands for running it. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: I believe you have to specify the scenario `./waf --run "vanet-routing-compare --scenario=1` (L84 from the link you shared)

Comment: @thenewjames   I also tried that, but there is still the same problem.

Comment: I suggest posting your question on the [NS-3 Users group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/ns-3-users)

Comment: I did this, thanks a lot @thenewjames

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error in version 3.31, but the version 3.30 is ok. Maybe you can also try version 3.30.

Answer (score 0):

I believe since version 3.31 the names changed from ns3::  to $ns3::

[https://groups.google.com/g/ns-3-users/c/VWTV9ZdY7fs/m/MxRdIoLoAAAJ[Here][1]](https://groups.google.com/g/ns-3-users/c/VWTV9ZdY7fs/m/MxRdIoLoAAAJ%5BHere%5D%5B1%5D)

The workaround I use is to copy the entire file from  here:[gitlab of ns3 development branch](https://gitlab.com/nsnam/ns-3-dev/-/blob/726199c94ef4848086b370d3c11bee020e86278b/src/wave/examples/vanet-routing-compare.cc)

As you can see, there were few (more than a few) changes in the code.